# Tell Hibernate to use @Version instead of @Id to check persistence state... using annotations?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am struggling with the problem described [here](http://onjava.com/onjava/2006/09/13/dont-let-hibernate-steal-your-identity.html). I have a persistent class that I want to make collection-safe by overriding `hashCode()` and `equals()`. Because my entity doesn't have a good natural key, these methods will need to use the `@Id` field, so I need to assign the id at the time of object creation. But now Hibernate will need another way to determine whether an instance is transient or persistent, and the logical field to use for that is `@Version`.

I know I could do this in an hbm file using `<version unsaved-value="null">`. But I've been using annotations, which don't support the `unsaved-value` attribute. If I just use the plain `@Version` annotation, will Hibernate be smart enough to use it to determine the persistence state? I've checked the Hibernate documentation, but it's a little ambiguous.

Does anyone know of a solution other than moving the mapping for the entire class into an hbm file?

Answer (score 0):

Think again at your entity model. If you can't find a natural key (even composite one) you might have a problem here.

Don't put your id in the equals()/hashCode() and use the @Version annotation only for its purpose. It will make your life harder.